# Aceder a um ficheiro .exe dentro de um ficheiro .jar

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Boas!

Sou novo em Java e estou a desenvolver um programa em que preciso de incluir em executável de um driver. Ao correr o ficheiro .jar, como posso fazê-lo executar o ficheiro .exe? Tenho que o extrair e depois correr ou posso corrê-lo internamente?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi direito o que você perguntou, você quer rodar um jar que execute um executável? Se for isso, você pode usar o método Runtime.exec(). Por exemplo,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping www.google.com");
```

Se você estiver interessado no return status ou no input/output stream, recomendo usar o ProcessBuilder.